# How else can I debug/rewrite the code below

Tags: php, pdo

I am building a user api and one of the task is to create user by inserting a user into the database but while I came up with a code it worked, but it returned 400 bad request as oppose to 200 ok status

```
create_user.php
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost/portal/user/");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control- 
Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// database connection will be here
// files needed to connect to database
include_once 'config/database.php';
include_once 'objects/user.php';

// get database connection
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// instantiate product object
$user = new User($db);

// submitted data will be here
// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// set product property values
$user->first_name = $data->first_name;
$user->last_name = $data->last_name;
$user->email = $data->email;
$user->password = $data->password;
$user->mobile_no = $data->mobile_no;
// use the create() method here

// create the user
if(
!empty($user->first_name)&&
!empty($user->last_name)&&
!empty($user->email)&&
!empty($user->password)&&
!empty($user->mobile_no)&&
$user->create()
){

// set response code
http_response_code(200);

// display message: user was created
echo json_encode(array("message" => "User was created."));
}

// message if unable to create user
else{

// set response code
http_response_code(400);

// display message: unable to create user
echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to create user."));
}
```

user.php (class)

```
<?php
// 'user' object
class User{

// database connection and table name
private $conn;
private $table_name = "users";

// object properties
public $uid;
public $first_name;
public $last_name;
public $email;
public $password;
public $mobile_no;

// constructor
public function __construct($db){
    $this->conn = $db;
}

// create() method will be here
// create new user record
function create(){

// insert query
$query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . "
        SET
            first_name = :first_name,
            last_name = :last_name,
            email = :email,
            password = :password,
            mobile_no = :mobile_no";

// prepare the query
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

// sanitize
$this->first_name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->first_name));

$this->last_name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->last_name));
 $this->email=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email));
 $this->mobile_no=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->mobile_no));   
$this->password=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->password));

// bind the values
 $stmt->bindParam(':first_name', $this->first_name);

$stmt->bindParam(':last_name', $this->last_name);

$stmt->bindParam(':email', $this->email);

 $stmt->bindParam(':mobile_no', $this->mobile_no);

// hash the password before saving to database
$password_hash = password_hash($this->password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password_hash);

// execute the query, also check if query was successful

if($stmt->execute()){
    return true;
}

return false;

}
}
```

?>

I expect to see a status code of 200 ok since i have inserted some values inside the body of the postman request. it was suppose to return 400 bad request if the values are empty

Comment: So it's returning 400 instead of a 200 you expect? What JSON are you sending? This a POST request?

Comment: Check your insert query.

Comment: Yes, it a POST request and this is what am posting {
    "first_name" : "Mike",
    "last_name" : "Dalisay",
    "email" : "mike@codeofaninja.com",
    "password" : "555555",
    "mobile_no" : "080590362455"
}

Comment: I stand corrected, MySQL uses non standard syntax. My thought was that the MySQL server was giving an error.

Comment: Why not log the SQL error if you are going to return a 400?

Comment: no error was found on the SQL error log